# How do I move the Bionic Beaver dock away from the left of the screen?

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-dock

By default under Bionic Beaver 18.04 LTS the dock is on the left of the screen and I would like to move it either to the bottom or the right of the screen. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

The good news is that this is easily accomplished under Bionic Beaver. Follow this navigation path:

```
Show Applications --> Settings --> Dock --> Position on screen
```

And from here you can select Left, Bottom or Right. See the screenshot below for the details:

[image]